# How to get email attachments with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, imap

I have managed to get text/html and text/plain parts of email, but now I need to get using `strtok($part->contentType, ';') == "text/plain"` and `strtok($part->contentType, ';') == "text/plain"` but now I need to get attachments (name, and to decode them). 
I have tried to do it via `Content-Disposition` equal to attachment, but I cant get to `Content-Disposition` from header array.
So my question is how to get attachments from email using IMAP and ZF2?
I saw couple similar questions like this and they are all submitted for previous version, I will need some newer solution.

Using Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap.

This is what I got when using `print_r( $part->getHeaders() );` (this is only email part with attachment) :

```
Zend\Mail\Headers Object
(
    [pluginClassLoader:protected] => Zend\Mail\Header\HeaderLoader Object
        (
            [plugins:protected] => Array
                (
                    [bcc] => Zend\Mail\Header\Bcc
                    [cc] => Zend\Mail\Header\Cc
                    [contenttype] => Zend\Mail\Header\ContentType
                    [content_type] => Zend\Mail\Header\ContentType
                    [content-type] => Zend\Mail\Header\ContentType
                    [date] => Zend\Mail\Header\Date
                    [from] => Zend\Mail\Header\From
                    [message-id] => Zend\Mail\Header\MessageId
                    [mimeversion] => Zend\Mail\Header\MimeVersion
                    [mime_version] => Zend\Mail\Header\MimeVersion
                    [mime-version] => Zend\Mail\Header\MimeVersion
                    [received] => Zend\Mail\Header\Received
                    [replyto] => Zend\Mail\Header\ReplyTo
                    [reply_to] => Zend\Mail\Header\ReplyTo
                    [reply-to] => Zend\Mail\Header\ReplyTo
                    [sender] => Zend\Mail\Header\Sender
                    [subject] => Zend\Mail\Header\Subject
                    [to] => Zend\Mail\Header\To
                )

        )

    [headersKeys:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => contenttype
            [1] => contentdisposition
            [2] => contenttransferencoding
            [3] => xattachmentid
        )

    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zend\Mail\Header\ContentType Object
                (
                    [type:protected] => application/octet-stream
                    [parameters:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => listen.pls
                        )

                )

            [1] => Zend\Mail\Header\GenericHeader Object
                (
                    [fieldName:protected] => Content-Disposition
                    [fieldValue:protected] => attachment; filename="listen.pls"
                    [encoding:protected] => ASCII
                )

            [2] => Zend\Mail\Header\GenericHeader Object
                (
                    [fieldName:protected] => Content-Transfer-Encoding
                    [fieldValue:protected] => base64
                    [encoding:protected] => ASCII
                )

            [3] => Zend\Mail\Header\GenericHeader Object
                (
                    [fieldName:protected] => X-Attachment-Id
                    [fieldValue:protected] => f_hlmfqj9o2
                    [encoding:protected] => ASCII
                )

        )

    [encoding:protected] => ASCII
)
```

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. Using strtok() is shouldn't proper way to get e-mail's parts. Your question is not clear. Which emails? When? While sending or receiving? Which classes and methods you currently utilizing? Are u trying to use Zend/Mail/Message class or not? Did u try to use getHeaderByName() or getHeaders() methods?

Comment: Using `strtok()` was on ZF2 documentation page as example so I used it from there. I am trying to fetch emails (content and attachments) from remote server via IMAP. I am using `RecursiveIteratorIterator()` to iterate over email parts and send them to user. I manage to send html and plain text but somehow I cant "separate" attachment parts from other parts. To reformulate question: How to know which email part is attachment and witch is not while using `RecursiveIteratorIterator()`?

Comment: I have managed to do something like this :

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getMessage($mail->countMessages() - 1)) as $part) {
       print_r($part->getHeaderField('Content-Disposition'));
       echo "<br/>";
    }
but since it is iterating in all email parts it trows  `Uncaught exception`.

Is it possible to do something like above? 
Am I doing it all wrong?